# Best way to arrange tick text using d3

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

By default when I set up ticks with D3, the text overlaps with the lines as follows:

[image: d3 ticks]

I am aware of two ways to correct this but both are flawed. The easiest way would be to add something like:

```
transform(0 -20px)
```

to the text element's css. the problem here is browser compatibility. The more browser-compatible way of doing things is:

```
d3.selectAll('text').attr('transform','translate(0,-20)')
```

The problem is that this won't work with dynamic scales; the function must run after the text elements have been appended so it's not compatible with transitionally updating tick scales.

Comment: Can you post the code you use to generate the axis and scale? By default there should be no overlap.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tickPadding for this. 
Example of calling axis with a padding of 20:

```
    axis.call(d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .tickSize(0)
    .tickPadding(20) )
```